# Comparing times in Apple Numbers

Tags: numbers

I am using the latest version of Apple Numbers on iOS.

I have a table with a Date/Time column, with values being:

```
=TIME(0,0,0)
=TIME(0,30,0)
=TIME(1,0,0)
```

and so on, in half-hour increments, for the entire day.

Now I want to count how many rows have a time greater than 18:00, so I try this:

```
=COUNTIF(TimeColumn, ">"&TIME(18,0,0))
```

This returns 0, whereas I expect about 11.

I have not been able to figure out how to set up this inequality.

What works:

1. `=COUNTIF(TimeColumn, TIME(18,0,0)` returns 1, as expected.
2. `=TIME(18,30,0) > TIME(18,0,0)` returns TRUE, as expected.

How do I count up the number of rows with a time greater than (or greater-than-or-equal-to) some constant time?

Comment: I haven't taken the time to experiment, but I suspect one workaround might be to convert the time values into plain numbers (which hopefully `COUNTIF` is happier with) using the `TIMEVALUE` function? I'm thinking: add another column calculating `TIMEVALUE` of your `TIME` values, then point `COUNTIF` at that new column. Hide the column if you don't want to see it.

Comment: @Ashley Thanks! That’s what I ended up doing. It works, though I would have preferred to find a solution without this crutch. Would you like to convert your comment to an answer?